# Can I use Prestone with already filled blue color coolant in Nissan Qashqai J11 Diesel 130ps in Germany

Tags: nissan, coolant, coolant-reservoir

**Update:**

I sent an email to `Nissan Car delear` from where I bought my car. I also called them and they redirected my number to the `mechanic`. He said that I could use any coolent `but not red color coolent`. When I asked if I could use `Prestone`, he said yes.

Later I received email from dealer, that I specifically have to use `Nissan L248 Coolent.` Unfortunatelly this `L248` is not avaialble in germany to buy which is very frustuating.

**Original:**

2019 I bought a Nissan Qashqai J11 Diesel 130ps 2016 model in Germany. Recently I have noticed that the coolant level is low. So I went to an `ATU` workshop and the guy sold me `Prestone` and told me I could mix it with any coolant.

At the moment my car has blue colored coolant (no idea about the brand). I went through the User Manual, and it doesn't specify any specific coolent.

On internet, half of the people are saying that we could mix any color and other half doesn't. It is very confusing for me as I am noob on this topic. Should I go with `Prestone` with my blue colored coolant?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think that nobody can give you a final answer: Nissan insists on using their original coolant. Prestone claims to be good for everything (something I doubt, as the different protection mechanisms differ quite a bit). I, personally, would get the original coolant and don't risk the engine over those few €.

Answer (score 1):

While not a totally reliable indicator, there are common colors that are used by many antifreeze manufacturers:

1. Green: Usually Ethylene-Glycol-based and is the most common type in non-GM vehicles.
2. Red or Orange: Dex-Cool used primarily in GM vehicles.
3. Blue: Propylene-glycol-based.

These types should NOT be mixed since that can caused problems with engine cooling.

Most engines that work with Ethylene-glycol can also use Propylene-glycol but you should drain and flush before changing.

Since you don't know for sure what you have there, and the color is not 100% reliable, you should either add distilled water to top-off a low system or flush and refill with the correct type specified by your owners manual.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to buy `Nissan L248 Collent` and will topup with it. I hard to buy online but I found one link to buy.

https://www.online-teile.com/nissan-ersatzteile/

One can search following part number to get it.

KE90299935

The Nissan dealers also have it but its far away from my residence place so I placed order online.